# Assign Color Using Seaborn Based on Column Name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, colors, seaborn

I'm trying to create 4 types of plots summarizing my data. I've included code to create 2 of the types of charts. I'm iterating over the crayon seaborn color palette to get a unique color for each chart. However, I would like the colors to be consistent for each column in my data set.

I created a few rows of fake data. My data looks like the following:

```
         Time  type1  type2  type3
0  2015-01-01    100    200    300
1  2015-02-01    150    250    350
2  2015-03-01    300    300    300
3  2015-04-01    350    350    350
```

Code:

```
#Setting up data 
import warnings
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
import sys
import seaborn as sns 

data = [{'Time': '201501','type1': 100, 'type2': 200, 'type3':300}, 
        {'Time': '201502' ,'type1':150, 'type2': 250, 'type3': 350}, 
        {'Time': '201503' ,'type1':300, 'type2': 300, 'type3': 300}, 
        {'Time': '201504' ,'type1':350, 'type2': 350, 'type3': 350}] 

data = pd.DataFrame(data) 

#Data prep

#setting index
data['Time']=pd.to_datetime(data['Time'], format='%Y%m')
data.set_index(['Time'], inplace=True)
#setting type for line graph
data=data.astype(float)

data

palette = itertools.cycle(sns.color_palette(palette=sns.colors.crayons))



############################# LINE PLOT ##################################################   

#this loops over each column in my data set and produces a graph

for i in data:  # Loop over all columns except 'Location'
    sns.set() #defaults the background
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    sns.set(style="ticks") 
    sns.lineplot(x=data.index,y=i,data=data,color=next(palette))  # column is chosen here
    sns.despine(offset=10, trim=True) 
    fig.set_size_inches(18,12)
    ax.set_title('{} History'.format(i), fontweight='bold')

    plt.savefig('{}.pdf'.format(i), bbox_inches='tight')  #sets file name based on column name


############################# VIOLIN PLOT ###############################################         
for i in data:  # Loop over all columns 
    sns.set() #defaults the background
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    sns.set(style="ticks") #darkens grid lines
    sns.violinplot(y=i, data=data,color=next(palette))  #sets which column to use
    sns.despine(offset=10, trim=True) 
    fig.set_size_inches(18,12)
    ax.set_title('{} Violin Plot'.format(i), fontweight='bold') #sets chart title based on column
    plt.savefig('{}_violin.pdf'.format(i), bbox_inches='tight')  #sets file name based on column name
```

[image]
[image]

When running the code, each chart has a unique color, but the line chart and the violin plot for type 1 do not have the same color. I would like the colors to be consistent across columns for each chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colors are being selected from an [infinitely cycling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) palette of colors:

```
palette = itertools.cycle(sns.color_palette(palette=sns.colors.crayons))
sns.lineplot(..., color=next(palette)) 
...
sns.violinplot(..., color=next(palette))
```

Each time `next(palette)` is called, the next color from the cycle is returned.
Thus, there is no color-coodination between lineplots and violinplots (unless by
miraculous coincidence or by design, `len(data.columns)` happens to be a
multiple of `len(sns.colors.crayons)`).

One way to get the lineplot and violinplot colors to be coordinated, is to reset the palette
before each loop:

```
palette = sns.color_palette(palette=sns.crayon_palette(sns.colors.crayons))
new_palette = itertools.cycle(palette)
for i in data:  # Loop over all columns except 'Location'
    ...
    sns.lineplot(x=data.index, y=i, data=data, color=next(new_palette))

...

new_palette = itertools.cycle(palette)
for i in data:  # Loop over all columns 
    ...
    sns.violinplot(y=i, data=data, color=next(new_palette))
```

Above, `palette` is just a list. `new_palette` is an infinitely cycling
iterator.  By creating a `new_palette` before each `for-loop`, 
`next(new_palette)` will return the same colors in the same order by both `for-loop`s.

Alternatively, perhaps a simpler way to achieve the desired result is to combine the two for-loops into one so that you could call `lineplot` and `vionlinplot` in the same iteration and pass the same color to both function calls.
Breaking up the code into functions can help clarify the intent of the code and keep the code looking tidy.

```
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

def make_data():
    data = [{'Time': '201501', 'type1': 100, 'type2': 200, 'type3': 300},
            {'Time': '201502', 'type1': 150, 'type2': 250, 'type3': 350},
            {'Time': '201503', 'type1': 300, 'type2': 300, 'type3': 300},
            {'Time': '201504', 'type1': 350, 'type2': 350, 'type3': 350}]

    data = pd.DataFrame(data)
    data['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Time'], format='%Y%m')
    data.set_index(['Time'], inplace=True)
    data = data.astype(float)
    return data

def make_lineplot(data, i, color):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    sns.set(style="ticks")
    sns.lineplot(x=data.index, y=i, data=data, color=color)  
    sns.despine(offset=10, trim=True)
    fig.set_size_inches(18, 12)
    ax.set_title('{} History'.format(i), fontweight='bold')
    plt.savefig('{}.pdf'.format(i), bbox_inches='tight')

def make_violinplot(data, i, color):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    sns.set(style="ticks")  
    sns.violinplot(y=i, data=data, color=color)  
    sns.despine(offset=10, trim=True)
    fig.set_size_inches(18, 12)
    ax.set_title('{} Violin Plot'.format(i), fontweight='bold')
    plt.savefig('{}_violin.pdf'.format(i), bbox_inches='tight')

data = make_data()


palette = itertools.cycle(sns.color_palette(palette=sns.colors.crayons))
# I had to use the line below to get the code to run
# palette = itertools.cycle(sns.color_palette(palette=sns.crayon_palette(sns.colors.crayons)))

for i, color in zip(data, palette):  
    make_lineplot(data, i, color)
    make_violinplot(data, i, color)
```

Comment: WOW. Thank you for such a detailed answer! Both options are amazing and well explained.

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises since you keep using `color=next(palette)` on each call. What you're looking for is a constant mapping between column name and color. The minimal changes needed in your code are:

```
...
palette = itertools.cycle(sns.crayon_palette(sns.colors.crayons))  # I get an exception for your version, but I guess this is equivalent to what you meant

palette = dict(zip(data.columns, palette)) # this creates a mapping between columns and colors

...
for i in data: 
    ...
    sns.lineplot(x=data.index, y=i, data=data, color=palette[i])
    ...
```

This way, each time you're plotting a line, the color used corresponds to a specific column rather than being continuously drawn from the iterator's `next` function.